# Why my OpenGrok full search always failed to get results?

Tags: java, tomcat, opengrok

My environment is the following:

win8 enterprise

tomcat 8.0.5 (can start up and access the home page successfully)

ctag ctags58

opengrok 0.9

jdk1.8.0_05

I copied all source code (C++ and C#) to OpenGrok\source, it is about 50GB.

Go to d:\opengrok in command windows, and run

java -Xmx1024m -jar lib\opengrok.jar -W "D:\OpenGrok\data\configuration.xml" -P -S -v -s "D:\OpenGrok\source" -d "D:\OpenGrok\data"

And under OpenGrok\data\index, there is about 1GB index files generated.

Configure the Tomcat with OpenGrok webapp by help document.

But, when I open http://www.mycomputername.com:8080/source, and input 'MonitorProc' in the "Full Search", I got Your search full:MonitorProc did not match any files. (I have checked that the file containing MonitorProc must be under OpenGrop\Source folder.

p.s: if I input 'class' as key word, I can got several results.

I wonder if there is some ways I could use to trouble shoot where the problem is? is the indexing problem? or Opengrok search issue? or any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use opengrok 0.12.1 , jdk8 is quite high for opengrok 0.9

Comment: Yeah, I updated openGrok to 0.12.1. When I input key word in "Full Search", I always got error message "Error: read past EOF". What's the meaning? thx.